# redux-observable: Returning interval from an Epic

Tags: rxjs, redux-observable

I'm trying to convert the following @ngrx effect to a redux-observable epic:

```
  @Effect()
  startReading$ =
    this.actions$.ofType('START_READING').switchMap(() => {
      return Observable.interval(200)
        .takeUntil(
          this.actions$.ofType('ABORT_PAGE_PROCESSING))
        .mapTo({ type: 'PROCESS_PAGE' });
    });
```

My attempt was to do:

```
export const startReadingEpic = action$ =>
  action$
    .ofType('START_READING')
    .switchMap(() =>
      Observable.interval(200)
        .takeUntil(action$.ofType('ABORT_PAGE_PROCESSING'))
        .mapTo({ type: 'PROCESS_PAGE' })
    );
```

which doesn't seem to work. Returning a single Observable.of({ type: 'PROCESS_PAGE' }) works fine though.

Did I miss anything required by redux-observable that is handled out-of-the box by @ngrx ?

Thanks.

Comment: The code looks correct. What exactly doesn't work? Could you log the actions?

Comment: I'm logging all actions getting through my application. There is nothing sent out of the epic when using the Observable.interval, version. It's getting sent out using Observable.of({ type: 'PROCESS_PAGE' })

Comment: Just to make sure: are there any errors in the console? Can you confirm that all needed rx operators got imported?

Comment: Agreed. Code looks fine. It's just normal Rx, agnostic of redux-observable or ngrx :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Code looks fine. It's just normal Rx, agnostic of redux-observable or ngrx (except for the `ofType` operator` but it's identical in both libraries)

Here it is, working:

https://jsbin.com/nosabuy/edit?js,output

There must be a problem somewhere else in your app. Check your console for errors, but if you don't see any you might try using "Pause on Caught Exceptions" in Chrome to see if maybe someone is swallowing an error silently. There's an outstanding RxJS bug where Rx itself may swallow errors and in the case of redux-observable it might affect you if there is an error in your reducers: https://github.com/redux-observable/redux-observable/issues/263. That said, I caution you not to immediately assume you're being bitten by this bug. Your debugger is your best friend here to confirm what's going on.

---

*This section is just to bypass stackoverflow's validation which wouldn't let me submit jsbin link without code*

```
// ignore this
```

Comment: I'm not getting any errors at all in the console, and "Pause on Caught Exceptions" doesn't trigger anything so it seems that no error is being thrown. I've tried with the timer and delay operators (and importing them), the issue is the same. The only supported output seems to be returning a single Observable, through Observable.of. I'm actually using React Native, could that be that these operators are not supported ?

Comment: Alright, I figured it out. I was debugging on an Android emulator, and all I needed to do is... to restart the emulator and it worked fine. Mobile dev is driving me crazy sometimes. Thanks a lot for your answer!